# c# Regex for numbers and dash only

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following in my c# code - what I like it to do is to check to see if the expression has numbers or a dash but nothing else. If I type in the letter K along with a dash or number it still accepts it. How do I say just have the express be numbers or a dash:

```
     Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9-]");
```

Note that input is the text that I am passing for evalution.

Comment: Your expression means there must be a number or dash somewhere within the string.  Not that it can *only* contain these characters and nothing else.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[0-9-]*$");
```

The `^` means that the match should start at the beginning of the input, the `$` that it should end at the end of the input.

The `*` means that (only) 0 or more numbers or dashes should be there (use `+` instead for 1 or more).

Comment: shouldn't the dash be escaped like this : `Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^[0-9\-]$");` ?

Comment: No, a dash at the start or end (between the `[]`) is a literal dash, not a range character.

Answer (score 10):

Your Regex matches that *any* digit or dash exists within the string, try the following:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"^[\d-]+$");
```

`^` Start of string

`[\d-]+` one or more digits or dashes

`$` End of string

Comment: Thanks, it works as I expected. When I type in a value, it does not accept say 9999K. What in the expression says do not accept any alpha values?

Comment: as described above, the regex says that only one or more digits or dashes can exist between the beginning and end of the string.  The reason yours allowed letters through was because you were only verifying that a digit or dash existed within the string.  The `^` and `$` make sure I am checking the entire string, not any part of it that happens to match.

Answer (score 8):

Any of the following Regex will work fine.

```
[0-9\-]+  ( + one or more occurance)

[\d\-]+ (as \d represents numbers)
```

if you want - must be between digits

```
[\d]+\-*[\d]+ will match any of following
90909900
9090-9009
900--900
```

if you want use only one - or no - between digits,
then

```
[\d]+\-?[\d]+ will match any of following
90909900 pass
9090-9009 pass
900--900 fail
```

Comment: [\d]+\-*[\d]+ is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the second dash.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9\-]");
```

I'll admit I didn't try it out, but it should work.

This will actually only work with one character. If you want it to take more than one character, like "123-5", then change your regex to..

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[0-9\-]+");
```

Comment: Sine the second - cannot be a range it is unnecessary to escape it

Comment: Take note in what @mynameiscoffey commented above about the `^` and `$` in your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If that's an array of strings, consider to get it done with LINQ?

```
if (arrInput.Any(s => (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[\d-]+$")))){ //OK }
```